# Is it possible for a variable to reference itself during a sequence of pipe operators, F#

Tags: f#

```
let sortStringAsKey (listOfWords : string array) = 
    let temp = listOfWords 
            |> Array.map (fun word -> word.ToCharArray() |> Array.sort)
            |> Array.map String
            |> Array.zip listOfWords
    temp
```

Hello,

I've written some code like this that takes a list of words and sorts them and it creates a tuple like such (originalWord, sortedWord) however; I would like the tuple to look like this (sortedWord, originalWord).

I know we could simply finish the let statement and then do

```
let newTemp = Array.zip temp |> listOfWords
```

But I was wondering if there's a way to somehow reverse the curried arguments somehow so that the first argument in function is applied first. This will let me do it without using another let statement.

EDIT:

What I was thinking was that somehow... if I could reference 'temp' I could use itself as the first argument into the zip or something... although I know that won't work since it can only take 1 function and it'd just zip it with itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could pipe the input into a lambda expression:

```
let temp = listOfWords 
  |> Array.map (fun word -> word.ToCharArray() |> Array.sort) 
  |> Array.map String 
  |> (fun sorted -> Array.zip sorted listOfWords)
```

Or you could generalize this and make yourself a function that reverses the arguments of another function. Such function is traditionally called `flip`:

```
let flip f a b = f b a

let temp = listOfWords 
  |> Array.map (fun word -> word.ToCharArray() |> Array.sort) 
  |> Array.map String 
  |> (flip Array.zip) listOfWords
```

As an aside, I personally would do it like this:

```
let pairWithSorted word = 
   let sorted = word |> Seq.sort |> Seq.toArray |> String
   sorted, word

let temp = listOfWords |> Array.map pairWithSorted
```

There's really no need for a `zip`, and no need for `ToCharArray`, because `string` is `IEnumerable<char>`.